# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need to update **total** field of tableA
with the result from the query

```
select SUM(amt)  from SALES group by DATE,RNAME
```

I tried like this

```
UPDATE tableA
SET Total = (
        SELECT Sum(billamt)
        FROM SALES
        GROUP BY DATE
            ,RNAME
        )
```

It shows following error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: This just means the the subquery returns more than 1 row. You should  make sure that the subquery returns only 1 row. You could use top 1.

Comment: Tried like this                                              **update tableA set Total= amt from (select sum(billamt)as amt from SALES group by DATE,RNAME)**. Still not working..:(

Comment: See BobTheBuilder's answer. If the subquery returns more than 1 row, it will produce an error.

Comment: Tried like this. still not working.  update tableA set Total=(select sum(b.BILLAMT) from  SALES b where  b.date>='2014-10-01' 
  and b.date<='2014-10-03' and tableA.RNAME=b.RNAME)

Comment: When grouping also by date, it still gives you three rows. Change it to: where b.date = '2014-10-02'. Does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
update A
set Total = B.Total
From tableA  A
Inner Join (select DATE,RNAME,sum(billamt) Total from SALES group by DATE,RNAME) B
On A.Date = B.Date and A.RName = B.RNAme
```

Comment: its working.. but total Null if Rname is null. how to update total if rname is not der in the table.

Comment: its working. but there is a case where Rname can be null in sales table. in that case i need to update with sum of bill amt on particular date.

Comment: Use another update statement for this case. This time just group by Date.

Comment: it worked..:) used another update statement as said.

Answer (score 4):

The query:

```
select sum(billamt) from SALES group by DATE,RNAME
```

Returns the `sum` of `billamt`, grouped by `DATE,RNAME`.

If you have more than one `DATE` or `RNAME` unique values, the returned value is a table (and not one field).

You can run this query alone and check the returned value.

As the error states, you cannot set more than one value to a field.

Comment: ohh.k then how can i update a table with sum of billamt of each Rname(person) for each day.. ?? actually am creating a temporary table and updating these fields for some specific reasons. is there any way to do so?

Comment: Tried like this. still not working.  update tableA set Total=(select sum(b.BILLAMT) from  SALES b where  b.date>='2014-10-01' 
  and b.date<='2014-10-03' and tableA.RNAME=b.RNAME)

Comment: Run this query: select sum(b.BILLAMT) from SALES b where b.date>='2014-10-01' and b.date<='2014-10-03' and b.RNAME='SOME_RNAME_VALUE'. It still should give you 3 rows as you select 3 dates.

Answer (score 2):

As the table structure is not clear in the above question, I assume that tableA has column Total, Date and RName

```
update tableA set tableA.total = 
a.total from (select SUM(amt) as total, date, rname from SALES group by DATE,RNAME) as a
where a.date = tableA.date and tableA.rname = a.rname
```

-- Edit for the "case where Rname can be null in sales table" use

```
update tableA set tableA.total = a.total
from (select SUM(amt) as total, date, rname from #t1 group by DATE,RNAME) as a
where a.date = tableA.date and tableA.rname = a.rname
OR (a.date = tableA.date AND tableA.rname IS NULL and a.rname IS NULL)
```

-- Further for elaboration

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (amt decimal(18,2), [date] date, rname varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #t1
SELECT 1.9, GETDATE() - 1, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 1.9, GETDATE() - 1, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 8.9, GETDATE() - 1, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 8.9, GETDATE(), NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2.9, GETDATE() - 1, 'N1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2.8, GETDATE() - 1, 'N1'

CREATE TABLE #t2 (total decimal(18,2), [date] date, rname varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #t2
SELECT 0, GETDATE() - 1, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, GETDATE() - 1, 'N1'

update #t2 set #t2.total = a.total
from (select SUM(amt) as total, date, rname from #t1 group by DATE,RNAME) as a
where a.date = #t2.date and #t2.rname = a.rname
OR (a.date = #t2.date AND #t2.rname IS NULL and a.rname IS NULL)


SELECT * FROM #t2
```

I hope its clear now

Comment: its working. but there is a case where Rname can be null in sales table. in that case i need to update with sum of bill amt on particular date.

Comment: @Indrah - see the edited answer and a complete example. I hope this will resolve your issue